# Change of window focus when developping with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have a setup using react. When i run yarn start, i can start coding and changes are visible in my browser. Problem is, every 10 secons or so my terminal wants to let me know about error in mycode and always change my focus back to my editor within the specific file where the error would be. it is so annoying and frustrating. I guess it has something to do with eslint. I tried looking at the doc and even erased the eslinrc.json file but still persist with the same behavior. Is there any way to stop that behavior.

here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "korean-recipes",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "yarn run start",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also run 'npm run start' or 'npm start' instead. To run your application and to see your changes in the browser.

Comment: Sorry sir, it doesnt adress the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is a behavior create by 'npx create-react-app' by default.
To remove the behavior, simply add a .env file with the following variable:
REACT_EDITOR=none

Source: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration